# Ошибка при импорте базы данных через консоль

Tags: mysql, openserver

Делаю в консоли (под админом) опенсервера команду

```
mysql -uuser -ppassword garage_db<D:\downloads\shopgarage_backup_2021-04-06\shopgarage_temp.sql
```

Получаю:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.62, for Win64 (AMD64)
Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Ora' at line 1
```

Гугл говорит что проблема может быть в кавычкам возе имени базы данных, я пробовал ставить ` и эти ' результат - 0

Comment: Ошибка явно говорит о том, что в первой строке вашего файла написана какая-то белиберда

Comment: ... в смысле с точки зрения структуры дампа БД - ерунда.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Погуглил, посмотрел файл дампа (а он жирненький, гигов 10) оказалось что дамб побился скорее всего при разархивации, и в начале строке оказался пробел лишний.